# Replace folder distanation of maven index

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

By default indexes download to `%user%/AppData/Local/Temp` and placed in user folder in windows os. Where is the property to setup destination folder? I not found this on maven configs or idea setup

Comment: TEMP variable ? But it is no just for maven.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For move maven index from temp folder and `c` disk completely you need to specify idea system folder in `idea.properties` file. For this action select in ide help-> edit custom properties. When file empty copy it content from `c:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2017.1.3\bin\idea.properties` file. Uncomment `idea.system.path` property and put complete path to new place in filesystem `idea.system.path=D:\\new_system_patch`. After that move content of old system folder to new destination.

Answer (score 0):

Try edit mvn.bat. At beginning

```
set TTT=%TMP%
set TMP=c:/Temp
```

At the end revert back variable value

```
set TMP=%TTT%
```